# AnyObject does not have a member named generator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

The problem is when I did the following

> for object in objects { eg: ....
>
> // [AnyObject] does not have a member named generator - It shows me
> this error
>
> }

And after my search in stackoverflow and some other sites I did this:

```
if objects?.count > 0 {

for object in objects! {

self.resultsUsernameArray.append(object.username) -> The error is "Cannot invoke append with an argument list of type (String?!)"

}

} else {

}
```

`[AnyObject]` does not have a member named generator || cannot invoke append with an argument list of type `(String?!)`

```
import UIKit

var userName = ""

class UsersViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var resultsTable: UITableView!

var resultsUsernameArray = [String]()
var resultsProfileNameArray = [String]()
var resultsImageFiles = [PFFile]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let theWidth = view.frame.size.width
    let theHeight = view.frame.size.height
    
    resultsTable.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, theWidth, theHeight - 64)
    
    userName = PFUser.currentUser()!.username!
    
}



override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username !="+userName+"'")
    var query = PFQuery(className: "_User", predicate: predicate)
    
    var objects = query.findObjects()
    
    for object in objects { // [AnyObject] does not have a member named generator
        
        self.resultsUsernameArray.append(object.username)
        self.resultsProfileNameArray.append(object["profileName"] as! String)
        self.resultsImageFiles.append(object["photo"] as! PFFile)
        
        resultsTable.reloadData()
        
    }

}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection eg..... {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if let username = object.username as String! {
  self.resultsUsernameArray.append(username)
}
```

Comment: No! not working. It shows "Cannot invoke append with an argument list of type (String?!)" Same again

Comment: It shows me this error: Downcast from 'String?!' to 'String' only unwraps optionals; didyou mean to use'!!'?

Answer (score 0):

`query.findObjects()` produces a `[AnyObject]?` (i.e. an `optional` which could be `[AnyObject]`). So, if the result from `query.findObjects()` is a `nil` it does not conform to the `Generator` protocol. So, first check whether your result is a nil and then unwrap it.

Your other problem with respect to `self.resultsUsernameArray.append(object.username)` is that `object` is now an `AnyObject` and that it does not have a property name `username`. You first need to cast `object` to `PFUser` and then use the `username` property.

```
var objects = query.findObjects()
if objects != nil {  // or use objects.count > 0
    for object in objects! {
        if let user = object as? PFUser {
            resultsUsernameArray.append(user.username!)
            ...
        }
    }
}
```